# Repeat a value in a column based on conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame called df.

There are four column in the data frame:

- change: to signify if its a new user (1  if yes)
- create: to signify if the user
  requested access (1 if true)
- delete: to signify if the user requested deletion of their id (1 if true)
- final:  to signify if we need to charge the user(if requested access for that day then its 1)

**Logic for the 'final' column:**

If 'create' is 1, then 'final' is 1, and this repeats till 'delete' is 1, the value resets (becomes whatever is in 'create') when there is a change of user (when 'change' is 1)

There is no possibility of 'create' and 'delete' both being 1, we handle the delete request the next day.

In terms of excel formula its like this:

**Formula:**

Assuming the headers starts at A1

```
=IF(A2=1,B2,IF(B2=1,1,IF(C3=1,0,D2)))
```

In terms of R this is what I have used so far:

Using mutate

```
df <- mutate(df, final =  ifelse(change == 1, create,
                          ifelse(create == 1, 1,
                          ifelse(delete == 1, 0, lag(final)))))
```

Using just ifelse

```
df$final <- ifelse(df$change == 1, df$create,
            ifelse(df$create == 1, 1,
            ifelse(df$delete == 1, 0, lag(df$final))))
```

**But the following just works:**

```
for (i in 1:NROW(df)){

  df$final[i] <- ifelse(df$chnaged[i] == 1, df$create[i],
                 ifelse(df$create[i] == 1, 1,
                 ifelse(df$delete[i] == 1, 0, df$final[i-1])))

}
```

**Expected Output: (got only if for loop code is used)**

```
change  create  delete  final
0       0       0       0
1       0       0       0
1       1       0       1
1       0       0       1
1       0       0       1
1       0       0       1
1       0       0       1
1       0       0       1
1       0       1       0
1       0       0       0
1       0       0       0
1       0       0       0
1       1       0       1
1       0       1       0
```

**Actual Output:**

```
change  create  delete  final
0       0       0       0
1       0       0       0
1       1       0       1
1       0       0       1
1       0       0       1
1       0       0       1
1       0       0       1
1       0       0       0
1       0       1       0
1       0       0       0
1       0       0       0
1       0       0       0
1       1       0       1
1       0       1       0
```

I can't figure out why this is happening, The crazy thing is excel implementation works fine, its only in R that I am facing this issue

P.S: R 3.30 on OSX el captain

**SAMPLE OF ACTUAL DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(username = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Label = c("admin", "user1", "user96"), class = "factor"), 
    create = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
    ), delete = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L)), .Names = c("username", "create", "delete"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-87L))
```

Comment: Why in `ifelse(change == 1, create, ...)` you want `create` and in `ifelse(df$change == 1, df$change, ...)` you want `change`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, final := ifelse(change == 1, create, ifelse(create == 1, 1, ifelse(delete == 1, 0, lag(final))))]
```

Comment: Sorry, if create = 1, then I am getting final =1, for next two rows only!. Thanks for trying though. I think the issue is with lag function

Comment: @user3875610, can you post example data.